# Create new jwplayer instance with same playlist from casting

Tags: javascript, casting, jwplayer, playlist

#### Wanted Behavior

I'm kind of trying to do what youtube is doing...
Browsing throught videos and having just one player in a single page application...

[image: skarmavbild 2018-04-09 kl 21 54 16]

And if I'm already casting a video to my chromecast then navigating away to select a other video or reloading the page and such i wishes to get the same cast session/playlist so that i can add a new video to the que or start to play right away

#### Current Behavior

When initiating another new player instance with a new video source when already casting something it dose not play that new source but instead lets me control the video that is being casted on to my TV.
Doe the poster for the new source are displayed but it's the wrong one for the current playing video

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
  cast: {appid: 'CC1AD845'},
  playlist: [{
    ...
  }]
});
```

#### What i would like to do is something along:

```
// 1. creating a player instance
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
// 2. Wait for ready event so the cast session can sync
// between the casting device and web with  playlist, current
// playing video, poster, seek and what not.
playerInstance.on('ready', (evt) => {
  // 3. get the playlist
  playerInstance.getPlayList()
  // add new video to the que, 
  // or stop playing the current video on the TV
  // or start playing the new video
})
```

I'm using 
jwplayer: 8.2.2
chrome: 65